# VueJS update v-for

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, v-for

I have an HTML element with `v-for` :

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in activeOutput">
```

When I change the output of `activeOutput`, the list on my website does not change. How can I tell Vue.js to update the `v-for`?

Comment: How do you update `activeOutput`?

Comment: activeOutput is a function.
In the function are varibale dependencys.
This variables are dependent from a checkbox

Comment: You mean a computed property?

Comment: Yes

When i chekck the checkbox, the output of this function change

Comment: Please show us there code, where you define `activeOutput`

Comment: I have definded it in the computed tag in the Vue app.
The code is to long.
In this Function is a return filter. When i click the checkbox, the function return a other list (other filter property)

Comment: If the code is too long to post here then you should shorten it to isolate the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It sounds like you have a reactivity problem but we won't be able to pin it down without some code to look at.

Comment: Have you tried the v-bind:key? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html